# Getting Attributes from iOS JSON Seralizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsdictionary

I have a simple JSON return which consists of the following:

```
{"GetMDXResponseResult":"{\" : [{\"cubeDatabaseName\" : \"Adventure Works DW 2008R2\",\"cubeName\" : \"Adventure Works\",\"cubeBaseName\" : \"\"},{\"cubeDatabaseName\" : \"Adventure Works DW 2008R2\",\"cubeName\" : \"Mined Customers\",\"cubeBaseName\" : \"\"}]}"}
```

What I am trying to do is use NSJSONSerialization to parse the file into a dictionary and then get back some attributes such as 'cubeName' into an array. I should note here that I have been following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on this subject along with several others and have come to no success. My problem is that the dictionary that is returned from the JSON serializer is returned just fine but when I try and get attributes from it into an array (as the tutorials generally show) the array always comes back null.

Here is my very simple code:

```
NSString *jsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GetMDXResponse(CubeQuery)" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilePath];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSArray *names = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"cubeName"];

NSLog(@"JSON Objects in Dictionary: %@",jsonDictionary);

NSLog(@"Cube Names: %@",names);
```

Here is the output of the first NSLog:

```
JSON Objects in Dictionary: {
GetMDXResponseResult = "{\" : [{\"cubeDatabaseName\" : \"Adventure Works DW 2008R2\",\"cubeName\" : \"Adventure Works\",\"cubeBaseName\" : \"\"},{\"cubeDatabaseName\" : \"Adventure Works DW 2008R2\",\"cubeName\" : \"Mined Customers\",\"cubeBaseName\" : \"\"}]}";
```

}

And the output of the second NSLog:

```
Cube Names: (null)
```

I've tried everything I could think of and have spent a week researching and going through Stack Overflow but nothing has helped. I've tried changing the dictionary to an array and vice versa, I tried enumerating the dictionary, I've tried getting an objectAtIndex, I've tried iterating through the array, nothing works. Everything other than what I posted usually results in the app crashing.

I'm completely out of ideas and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your JSON dictionary only has one value, which is a string. The contents of that string are not themselves valid JSON. Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: As Josh said (20 seconds before me:), your JSON returns dictionary whose value is, itself, another JSON string which you'd have to parse again. This is a confusing structure. Are you able to change that JSON to something more logical? Or are you stuck with that structure? We can tell you how to parse this JSON, but I'd rather advise that you change the structure of the original JSON if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, it's beginning to make more sense now. I'm getting the JSON from a return of a query which is made to a web service. We (my company) control the query structure and the web service so, yes, it is possible for us to change the structure.

Comment: May I ask what a valid JSON would like? I ask this because I've ran the JSON I posted above through a validator and it did, in fact, come back valid. Could one of you post an example or two? It is clear the examples we have been following are not altogether correct. Thanks.

Comment: The _string_ is valid JSON, yes; it's just the value of the key `"GetMDXResponseResult"`, but if the _contents_ were to be interpreted as also being JSON -- unquoting the string, in effect -- then you have a missing key/stray `"` right at the beginning, which is not valid.

Comment: Thank you both, Josh and Rob, for your insight. With it I was able to go back and restructure our JSON and then get attributes from it.